# How can I read JSON from a file stored locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am attempting to use JSON.Net to load in a JSON file stored locally on an ASP.Net MVC 4 site, but am having trouble pointing to the file. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
List<Treatment> treatments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Treatment>>(Server.MapPath("~/Content/treatments.json"));
```

and am hitting this error:

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Post the JSON file, please.

Comment: Looks like your JSON might not be properly formated or it might have single quote in a wrong place

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to read in the JSON first using a `FileStream`.

Try this.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Content/treatments.json")))
{
      treatments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Treatment>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You are passing in the *path and filename* as your JSON payload.  You need to open the file (eg. `FileStream`) and read the contents into a variable (eg. `StreamReader`) and pass the file contents as the payload to the deserializer.