# Accessing a single value from a json file in c#

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

My json file looks something like this

```
{
lab :[
{
    "name": "blah",
    "branch": "root",
    "buildno": "2019"
}]
}
```

so, i need to access the value of the buildno (2019) and assaign it to a variable in my program.

This is my class

```
public class lab
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string branch { get; set; }
    public string buildno { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this method using Newtonsoft.json

```
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"ba.json"))
        {
            string json2 = r.ReadToEnd();
            lab item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<lab>(json2);
            Console.WriteLine(item.buildno);
        }
```

But I'm not getting any output!!! only blank screen.

Comment: can you try out newtonsoft , let me know if there is any issue

Comment: Your JSON file and your class do not match. In your JSON file you have an attribute `lab` that is an !->`array`<-!, which then holds objects that match the class that you posted in your question. Make 2 classes, one with the property `lab` that is a List<T> of the child classes.

Comment: @Pranay Rana I've just updated the question.. Still no luck  :(

Comment: @DodgerThud  can you please explain what I'm supposed to do with the 2nd class?

Comment: @AbhishekKSuresh - updated my answer have look , json strucutre given by you in question is incorrect

Comment: @Pranay Rana Now?

Comment: @AbhishekKSuresh - yesh its look simi;ar to my json now, you also need to change your class strtucture as suggested in answer ... and then give a try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

Comment: is that worked for you

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the following function to get a single value from json.

> JObject.Parse()

Just pass the json returned by any of API's (if you are using) as a parameter to Parse function and get the value as follows:

```
// parsing the json returned by OneSignal Push API 
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
int noOfRecipients = json.recipients;
```

I was using OneSingal API to send push notifications and on hitting their API it returned a json object. And here 'recipients' was basically a key returned in the json.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I've tried this dynamic json1 = JObject.Parse(@"C:\Users\ab\Desktop\Output\Sample\ba.json"); 
 And I'm getting this error ----       Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648030/how-can-i-read-json-from-a-file-stored-locally
Take a look here, might help you.

Answer (score 1):

jsong structure , given by you

```
{
lab :[
{
    "name": "blah",
    "branch": "root",
    "buildno": "2019"
}
}
```

its not valid json structure , it should be like this

```
{
lab :[
{
    "name": "blah",
    "branch": "root",
    "buildno": "2019"
}]
}
```

and then you C# class structure for that is

```
public class Lab
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string branch { get; set; }
    public string buildno { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Lab> lab { get; set; }
}
```

if you do that then below code will work or code you are trying will work.

---

make use of Deserialize/serialize to convert you json in .net object type :make use of Newtonsoft library : [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Example :

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
Console.WriteLine( account.Email);
```

Comment: I've tried the exact same method, but I'm not getting any outputs.    Console.WriteLine(item.buildno);  ==  Nothing!!!

Comment: @AbhishekKSuresh - can you please share your code and json you tried

Comment: @Pranay I think the difference is that your JSON flat object, whereas OP's "lab" property points to an array of objects.

Comment: @john - i though so , thats why i requested him to provide full json with code tried because without that its just guessing work

Comment: He provided enough information, you can clearly see its an array from his OP.

Comment: @DodgerThud - that is not valid json structure ..that why it wont work

Answer (score 0):

First of all you create a json object by

```
var lab = JSON.stringify({
    "name": "blah",
        "branch": "root",
        "buildno": "2019"
    });
```

then you can get this json object like this

```
dynamic model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(lab);
```

then you get value like as

```
  lab l = new lab();
  l.buildno =  model.buildno;
```

Hopefully this help for you.

Comment: I can't create an object an object and directly give data. ---- I have to read data from a file.

Comment: Please follow this tutorial    https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

Comment: Another solution you can follow [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774795/deserialize-json-from-file-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa