# How to get the value of a particular field from JSON token using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the below JSON which I have parsed into JToken 'token'.

```
{
  "base": {
    "employees": {
      "employeewage": {
        "employeeids": [
          {
            "employeeid": "AA",
            "details": [
              {
                "position": "Tester",
                "salary": 8500,
                "currency": "INR"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the value of 'salary' field alone. The code I tried,

```
var salary = token.SelectToken("$.base.employees.employeewage.employeeids.details.salary").ToString();
```

I am getting exception with this. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: The easiest way is to deserialize it to a complete C# object, and then just choose the fields you want from the C# object.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480417/accessing-a-single-value-from-a-json-file-in-c-sharp).

Comment: You should access it as an array

Comment: You should add exception if you have one)

Comment: Not an explicit answer to your question, but if you create a class and use this custom deserializer, then you should accomplish what you want:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088462/can-i-specify-a-path-in-an-attribute-to-map-a-property-in-my-class-to-a-child-pr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`employeeids` and `details` are an arrays, so you should reflect it and enumerate them after parsing

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var employees = json["base"]?["employees"]?["employeewage"]?["employeeids"];

foreach (var detail in employees.SelectMany(e => e["details"]))
{
    var salary = detail["salary"]?.Value<string>();
}
```

Or get the first item of all `details` from all employees

```cs
var salary = employees.SelectMany(e => e["details"]).FirstOrDefault()?["salary"]?.Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@Pavel Anikhouski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728685/pavel-anikhouski) said in the comments you have arrays (`employeeids` and `details`) in your json, so you need to add array handling to the path:

```
var x= @"{
  'base': {
    'employees': {
            'employeewage': {
                'employeeids': [
                  {
            'employeeid': 'AA',
                    'details': [
                      {
                'position': 'Tester',
                        'salary': 8500,
                        'currency': 'INR'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}";

var salary = JToken.Parse(x)
    .SelectToken("$.base.employees.employeewage.employeeids[0].details[0].salary")
    .ToString();
```

Also see examples in the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).